# SQL - Store a calculated value (based on child tables) in a column or calculate in data model?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, database-design, database-optimization

I have run into a little quandry, and I'm hoping the SO community can help me out with this one.

I'm currently in a situation where we are writing custom logic for order discounts, which are based on configurable rules.  In it's simplest form, here are the tables:

**Order**

```
OrderID int
```

**OrderDiscount**

```
OrderID int
DiscountID int
```

**Discount**

```
DiscountID int
```

We are using Entity Framework (but this question could apply to any data model).  I feel like my options are simple, but both have their drawbacks:

1. Add a column "Discount" to my SQL *Order* table.  Drawbacks:  Any time an order is updated, we will need to remember to recalculate the discount and update this column.  This could cause data inconsistency, but will perform better.  Will also allow discount amount to be overridden.
2. Add a "Discount" property to my *Order* Data Model in-code.  Drawbacks:  Requires calculation any time this property is accessed, but will always be accurate.

Which route should I go and why?

Comment: or 3. use a trigger on the table update, and you don't have to remember the recalculation and you are always accurate. I pick option 1 with remark.

Comment: I would agree that triggers would solve this problem, but I have many problems with triggers:  deployment of database schema updates is more difficult, no source control, causes deadlocks if you're not careful, and an overall maintenance headache.

Comment: I sense a certain dislike to triggers. Yes, they introduce some complexity, but they also solve a problem. Question is, is the solution to the problem worth the effort. I wouldn't call triggers an overall maintainance headache, but that's just me. Can't you choose option 2 and calculate the discount in the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

You are neglecting two key accounting requirements

1. The discount for each order, along with the details of how each discount is calculated, MUST be stored in each respective order; because once the order is posted to the GL it MUST NOT BE ALLOWED to change. Posted orders can be cancelled or reversed, but cannot be changed.
2. However, while the order is being built, but has not yet been posted to the GL, the rules are different - the discount mUST be recalculated live, which is most easily enforced by NOT storing it in the record.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, story calculated fields in the database is not considered a best practice unless the the time consumed by the calculations is significant, I'd chose to implement the calculation in the constructor rather than storing a new value each time the discount value is changed.
check out this link for an extended view on the subject.
[HERE](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/01/database-skills-third-normal-form-and.html)